# I am making one project using react and nodejs but the data cannot get passed to database since i am using mysql these are the files

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'


function App() {

const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
const [title,setTitle] = useState("");

const addPassword= ()=>{
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/addpassword",{
    password: password,
    title:title
  });
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="AddingPassword">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. password:123" onChange={(event)=>{
          setPassword(event.target.value)}}/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Facebook" onChange={(event)=>{
          setTitle(event.target.value)}}/>
        <button onClick={addPassword}>Add Password</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nodejs

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = 3001;

app.use(cors()); // this will allow use to make connection between two servers in local machine.
app.use(express.json()); //this will make the use of json file using express

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password: "root",
    database: "passwordmanager",
})

app.post("/addpassword",(req,res)=>{
    const {password,title} =req.body;

    db.query("INSERT INTO passwords (password,title) VALUES (?,?)",[password,title],(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.send("Success");
        }
    })
})
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("server is running")
})
```

I am not getting error but yes db is not getting connected and also the values are not getting pushed in the table. Help me community!

so the data is not getting passed to mysql database. I am likely looking for some possible solution.
->db not getting connected

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line to your mysql workbench this happens due to connection issue between the system and the mysql due to password.

Write the below line above the select line in workbench, it worked for me

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';